# defining a new variable for counting group element with another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 columns, HHVEH  and a group SAMPN. all member of SAMPN have the same HHVEH. I want to define a new column which in each group is 2 until the number of HHVEH.

example

```
          SAMPN      PERNO HHVEH
            1          1     1
            1          2     1
            1          3     1
            2          1     2
            3          2     2
            3          3     2
            4          4     0
            4          3     0
```

output

```
          SAMPN      PERNO HHVEH      mode.car
            1          1     1           2
            1          2     1           NA
            1          3     1           NA
            2          1     2           2
            3          2     2           2
            3          3     2           2
            4          4     0          NA
            4          3     0          NA
```

explain:  first group HHVEH==1 so first row is 2 and others NA. second group HHVEH==2 So first 2 roes of it should be 2 but there is just one row so that row is 2. third group HHVEH==2 both get 2 last group HHVEH==0 so NA for all.

```
structure(list(SAMPN = c("  827", "  827", " 1133", " 1133", 
" 1133", " 1133", " 1133", " 1133", " 1857", " 1857", " 1857"
), HHVEH = c(3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), PERNO = structure(c(2L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), groups = structure(list(SAMPN = c("  827", " 1133", " 1857"
), .rows = list(1:2, 3:8, 9:11)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


  SAMPN   HHVEH PERNO      mode.car
   <chr>   <dbl> <fct>
 1 "  827"     3 2            2
 2 "  827"     3 4            2
 3 " 1133"     2 4            2
 4 " 1133"     2 3            2 
 5 " 1133"     2 3            NA
 6 " 1133"     2 5            NA
 7 " 1133"     2 1            NA
 8 " 1133"     2 1            NA
 9 " 1857"     3 3            2
10 " 1857"     3 2            2
11 " 1857"     3 3            2
```

Comment: I have a doubt, if for one of the rows is 0 and the next one is 1 or 2, (SAMPN - 4) what is the output

Comment: the output is 2 for HHVEH elements of the household. start from top of each group

Comment: Can you update with the expected for the new dataset.  I get `[1]  2 NA  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 NA NA`

Comment: no I updated. in second group HHVEH==2 so first 2 row of this group is 2 and NA for rest

Comment: It is not clear.  ere the `1857'  'HHVEH' starts with 3.  why is the 'mode.car'  2 also fro 1133' the values are all 2 for HHVEH', how are some rows getting NA there.  Also for 827, the first row is HHVEH -3, and how are all the rows getting filled with 2

Comment: HHVEH is for each SAMPN. HHVEH is same for all members of a group. and for example if HHVEH==2 for a group this means that we need 2 elements of the group to be 2 from the top.

Comment: in SAMPN==1857, HHVEH==3 so  3 first member of the SAMPN==1857 should be 2 and rest NA, and there are just 3 rows

Comment: in SAMPN==1133 , HHVEH==2 so the first 2 rows of SAMPN==1133 must be 2 and NA for rest

Comment: Is the logic something like `df1 %>% group_by(SAMPN) %>% mutate(mode.car = rep(c(2, NA_integer_), c(first(HHVEH), pmax(0, n() - first(HHVEH)-1))))`

Comment: Error: Column `mode.car` must be length 2 (the group size) or one, not 4

Comment: thanks, please check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option based on the updated data.  After grouping by 'SAMPN', create the 'mode.car' by `rep`licating the 2 based on the `first` value from 'HHVEH' and the rest with the  `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(SAMPN) %>% 
   mutate(mode.car = rep(c(2, NA_integer_), 
           c(pmin(n(), first(HHVEH)), pmax(0, n() - first(HHVEH)))))
# A tibble: 11 x 4
# Groups:   SAMPN [3]
#   SAMPN   HHVEH PERNO mode.car
#   <chr>   <dbl> <fct>    <dbl>
# 1 "  827"     3 2            2
# 2 "  827"     3 4            2
# 3 " 1133"     2 4            2
# 4 " 1133"     2 3            2
# 5 " 1133"     2 3           NA
# 6 " 1133"     2 5           NA
# 7 " 1133"     2 1           NA
# 8 " 1133"     2 1           NA
# 9 " 1857"     3 3            2
#10 " 1857"     3 2            2
#11 " 1857"     3 3            2
```

Comment: I tried on a data that I put in question now. it does not give me th correct output.

Comment: @hghg What is the expected for that new data